# Navigating through yaml files using variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml

The title is kind of bad, but I will try my best to explain it.

What I'm trying to do is pretty much navigate through a yaml file as you normally would

```
var doc = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('./settings.yml', 'utf8'));
console.log(doc.admin.permissions);
```

except I want to be able to do this:

```
var adminrolename = "admin1";
console.log(doc.adminrolename.permissions);
```

Is there a way I could do this? I've been looking around and I can't seem to find an answer, I might just be searching for the wrong thing, so sorry if this has an obvious answer

Comment: did you try `doc[adminrolename].permissions` ?

Comment: 90% Sure I did, but I'll check again in case (ill edit my post stating that i tried that) -update, didnt work :/

Another update, just had a thought that might work, sorry if it does and not realising it sooner, will update shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did for a proof of concept. Remember that keys are case sensitive so `doc["admin"]` won't be same as `doc["Admin"]`

Yaml File:

```
doc:
  admin:
    permissions:
      - abc
      - xyz
  admin1:
    permissions:
      - abc1
      - xyz1
```

JS File:

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const fs = require('fs');
try {
    const config = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('test.yml', 'utf8'));
    const doc = config.doc;
    console.log(doc["admin"].permissions);
    console.log(doc["admin1"].permissions);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Result:

```
[ 'abc', 'xyz' ]
[ 'abc1', 'xyz1' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone for the inconvenience, @Kinaan Khan Sherwani was right, I did try it, but I messed up the yaml file.

```
doc[adminrolename].permissions
```

That is what the correct code is

I didn't put any quotes around the sections... *facepalms*. Here's what the original YAML was:

[image: what the original image was]

This is what I changed the YAML to, to fix my problem:

[image: what i changed the yaml to]

Comment: I think it might be due to the case insensitivity. Adding quotes won't have any effect :)

Comment: If that was the reason i will cry hahah (not really tho)
Also thanks for the reply

Comment: An upvote would be great if my example serves the purpose, haha !